# Track users activities for log and pricing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can i log the users activities in order to track their actions and calculate how much each user cost for my firebase project?

I don't need to have it in low level, but some data like when the user logged in, from where (network), what page it loads, and so on...

Do I have to implement the bread crumbs, or there is something I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no per-user usage tracking built into Cloud Firestore. If you need that for your app, you will have to build it yourself.

You can either build this into the application code directly (and securing it through Firestore's server-side security rules), or you can implement the tracked operations in Cloud Functions.

Comment: Thanks @frank-van-puffelen for this confirmation :-)

I follow all your videos on youtube. I am your (all) fan #1!

Comment: You're welcome Jorge. I hope to see you at the Firebase Summit in Prague then. :-)